# Azure .Net MVC Custom Response.StatusDescription are not sent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I try to use custom StatusDescription to send a message along with my content to the client. On my local machine it works but on Azure it don't. Does someone know why?

Regards, Alex

**Update:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Order = 1)]
public ActionResult SaveCustomer(KundenViewModel viewModel)
{

    /*
     * Do some additional stuff here
     */

    try
    {
        // Save the customer in database
        SaveCustomerToDatabase(viewModel);
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        Response.StatusDescription = Global.SaveCustomerSuccess; // <---  Try to response a message
        return PartialView("_CustomerTable", GetCustomerViewModel();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogException(e, HttpContext);
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        Response.StatusDescription = Global.GeneralErrorInternal; // <---  Try to response a message
        return null;
    }
}
```

And on the client side I try to display the message:

```
MyNamespace.customerSaveSuccess = function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    MyNamespace.Notification.Success(jqXHR.statusText);
    _ToggleTabs(false);
};
```

If I try this local it works perfect but as soon as I publish it to Azure I get just the default status code message "OK" and not my custom text

Comment: how can we possibly tell without seeing any of your custom code?

Comment: In short: nope. A bit longer: please make sure we can check what you're encountering, for instance by adding (relevant) code. For more info, please refer to this article: [mcve]

Comment: @rickvdbosch OP has provided some code.

Answer (score 0):

I added the "existingResponse" attribute to the httpErrors element in web.config to allow the response body to pass through to the client in Azure.  I had the same issue where I could see the message only locally. Hope this helps!

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```